# Fast and Clean way to find to find Numpy arrays index

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I'll try to be clear. The problem is:

I have two arrays, ELEM and LAMI.

The ELEM array contains information of a Finite Element model, it is of type:

```
ndtype= [('conn','i4',3),('sets','a12',2)]
```

so typical data for ELEM is:

```
array([ ([47, 49, 36], ['web', 'gelcoat']),
([48, 30, 43], ['surf', 'balsa']),...])
```

Now, LAMI contains data for a lamination sequences that can be used for the elements of ELEM. LAMI is of type:

```
ndtype = [('name', 'a12', 1), ('type', 'a12', 1), ('cons', 'float64', 6)]
```

So, for example

```
In[1]:LAMI
Out[1]:array([ ('udfrp', 'TRISOTROPIC', [37.0, 90.0, 4.0, 4.0, 0.28, 1860.0]),
           ('dbfrp', 'TRISOTROPIC', [10.0, 10.0, 8.0, 8.0, 0.3, 1830.0]),
           ('gelcoat', 'ISOTROPIC', [10.0, 0.3, 1830.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]),
           ('nexus', 'ISOTROPIC', [1.0, 0.3, 1664.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]),
       ('balsa', 'TRISOTROPIC', [10.0, 10.0, 2.0, 2.0, 0.3, 128.0])], 
      dtype=[('name', 'S12'), ('type', 'S12'), ('cons', '<f8', (6,))])
```

As it can be seen, ELEM['sets'][1] is the name of the material of the element, the material properties of the element are stores in LAMI['cons'].

And the question is: Whichs is the best way to find the array of material properties for an element? I've tried the following:

```
index = np.where(LAMI['name'][0] == ELEM['sets'][element,1])]
prop_array = LAMI['cons'][index]
```

But I'm sure there must be a better way to do that. Thanks!

Comment: If it works, why change?

Comment: Because the syntax is very unclear and it is very difficult to read.

Comment: @Martin I can not see any column called `sets` in ELEM table. Can you post complete data or more details?

Comment: @Dalek, actually there is a column called sets, ndtype= [('conn','i4',3),('sets','a12',2)]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Converting the array to a dictionary would simplify the access a bit

```
In [163]: Ldict={}
In [166]: for r in LAMI:
   .....:     Ldict[r['name']]={'type':r['type'],'cons':r['cons']}

In [176]: name=ELEM['sets'][0,1]

In [177]: LAMI[np.where(LAMI['name']==name)]['cons']
Out[177]: 
array([[  1.00000000e+01,   3.00000000e-01,   1.83000000e+03,
          0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00]])

In [178]: Ldict[name]['cons']
Out[178]: 
array([  1.00000000e+01,   3.00000000e-01,   1.83000000e+03,
         0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00])
```

Another approach would be to define a `Material` class, so each `material` is an object.  The `ELEM` array could then have an `object` field with these pointers.

Do you ever use `LAMI['cons']` as a whole array?  If not the structured array format might not be all that useful.

---

A version using a Material object:

```
class Material(object):
    def __init__(self, name, _type, cons):
        self.name = name
        self.type = _type
        self.cons = cons.tolist() # more compact display
    def __repr__(self):
        return str((self.name, self.type, self.cons))
Ldict = {}
for r in LAMI:
    Ldict[r['name']] = Material(r['name'], r['type'], r['cons'])

dset = np.dtype([('where','a12'),('material','O')])
dtElem = np.dtype([('conn', '<i4', (3,)), ('sets', dset)])
# nested dtypes
# [('conn', '<i4', (3,)), ('sets', [('where', 'S12'), ('material', 'O')])]

ELEM = np.array([ ([47, 49, 36], ('web', Ldict['gelcoat'])),
                  ([48, 30, 43], ('surf', Ldict['balsa']))],
               dtype=dtElem)

print 'ELEM array'
print ELEM
print 'material properties of one element'
print ELEM[0]['sets']['material'].cons
print 'materials of all elements'
print ELEM['sets']['material']
```

producing:

```
ELEM array
[ ([47, 49, 36], ('web', ('gelcoat', 'ISOTROPIC', [10.0, 0.3, 1830.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0])))
 ([48, 30, 43], ('surf', ('balsa', 'TRISOTROPIC', [10.0, 10.0, 2.0, 2.0, 0.3, 128.0])))]

material properties of one element
[10.0, 0.3, 1830.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]

materials of all elements
[('gelcoat', 'ISOTROPIC', [10.0, 0.3, 1830.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0])
 ('balsa', 'TRISOTROPIC', [10.0, 10.0, 2.0, 2.0, 0.3, 128.0])]
```

But to get a list of the `cons` of all elements I'd have to use a comprehension:

```
print [m.cons for m in ELEM['sets']['material']]
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. Actually I don't use the LAMI array as an array but just as a data container. May it be that there is an additional cost if I store in ELEM['sets'] an object?

Comment: This `dtype` should be just as good: `dtype([('conn', '<i4', (3,)), ('sets', 'S12'), ('material', 'O')])`.  A pointer to an object is just as compact as a string.  It's probably possible to nest the 'material' field in the 'sets' field, but I haven't worked out the syntax.

Comment: I've sketched a variation with material objects, and a field in `ELEM` that points to that.  For some tasks class encapsulation is nice, for others, arrays and tables are better.

Comment: Excellent hpaulj ! This helps me a lot, this is the approach I will follow, I think there is no extra cost in this approach because although there are many many elements, the ELEM array only stores the pointer to the material object. Since there are few materials in the the models the extra cost of instancing and object over reading the properties from an array is negligible. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

In this case, a [dictionary](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#mapping-types-dict) would probably be preferred:

```
In [4]: LAMId = {x['name']: LAMI[['type','cons']][i] for i, x in enumerate(LAMI)}

In [5]: LAMId['udfrp']
Out[5]: ('TRISOTROPIC', [37.0, 90.0, 4.0, 4.0, 0.28, 1860.0])

In [6]: LAMId['udfrp']['cons']
Out[6]: 
array([  3.70000000e+01,   9.00000000e+01,   4.00000000e+00,
         4.00000000e+00,   2.80000000e-01,   1.86000000e+03])
```

Comment: Thanks Banana! This is part of what I'm going to do, the rest is following hpaulj recommendation and store the material properties in a column in ELEM that contains a pointer to a material property object.